# How do I replace only PART of an image source on hover using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<li class="active"><a href="#"><img src="images/static/personal_information.png" class="img-responsive center-block"><span>Personal<br> Information</span> </a></li>
```

This is what i trying

```
$(".navbar-nav li a").hover(function(){
        $(this).children("img").attr('src').replace('hover','static');
});
```

Comment: Just switch the entire image with another one. That is, the img element.

Comment: Serial downvoter on site... would downvoter care to comment on perfectly valid answers?

Comment: @SimeonSimeonoff Nope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your arguments to `replace()` are the wrong way around. Secondly, you need to actually set the value after making the replacement. Lastly you'll also need to provide another function argument to `hover()` that sets the original image back on mouseout. Try this:

```js
$(".navbar-nav li a").hover(function() {
  $(this).children("img").prop('src', function(i, src) {
    return src.replace('static', 'hover');
  })
}, function() {
  $(this).children("img").prop('src', function(i, src) {
    return src.replace('hover', 'static');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="images/static/personal_information.png" class="img-responsive center-block">
      <span>Personal<br> Information</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I added a snippet as at least 2 people don't believe this works for some reason

Comment: Hey bro ! thanks i just wnat to know why do you pass i parameter with function and what is does (I am new to jquery).

Comment: The `i` argument is the index of the element in the set. Here's the docs for it: http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-function

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing `src` code, but not assigning it back.

```
$(".navbar-nav li a").hover(function(){
    var newSrc = $(this).children("img").attr('src').replace('hover','static');
     $(this).children('img').attr('src', newSrc)
});
```

Comment: Just FYI the `replace()` arguments are the wrong way around

Answer (score -1):

Why are you targeting `<a>`, then select its child `<img>`? Why not apply that to the image directly?

```
$(".navbar-nav li a img").hover(function(){
    $(this).attr('src') = $(this).attr('src').replace('hover','static');
});
```

Comment: The OP targets the `a` because it also contains some text as well as the `img` and presumably they want to change the src when that text is hovered too. Also, the `replace()` arguments are the wrong way around

Comment: Okay, fair enough.